# Copy a packed array to unpacked array

Tags: system-verilog

I wrote a code for copying a packed array to an unpacked array as below:

```
module m1;

bit [2:0] temp;
bit temp1[2:0];
initial
begin
temp=3'b011;
temp1='{temp};
end 
endmodule
```

But it showing an error: "Too few assignment pattern items for given assignment"
Solution please.

Answer (score 3):

Packed array and unpacked array are different data structure, it cannot be directly assigned from another type.

Using assignment pattern for array must be either positional based or index based. For example,

```
temp1 = '{temp[2], temp[1], temp[0]};
```

The solution is using streaming operator at LHS of the assignment.

```
{>>{temp1}} = temp;
```

Comment: {>>{temp1}} = temp;
This does not work.
And for the upper one, we can directly assign the values with out "'" operator or casting.
like temp1 = {temp[2], temp[1], temp[0]};
But i need alternative one to assign the values directly.

Comment: Please comment what the simulator you are using. Streaming operator on LHS might be not valid or implemented in some simulator or synthesizor.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a size parameter. This should work:

```
parameter MYSIZE = 3;
bit [MYSIZE-1:0] temp1;
bit temp2[0:MYSIZE-1];

{>> MYSIZE{temp2}} = temp1;
```

I know this works on VCS.